# How to get number of NIC RX rings in Linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I've try to get count of NIC RX rings from my programs via ETHTOOL API and 
command ETHTOOL_GCHANNELS, but program returns error: "Operation not supported."
Sample code:

```
echannels.cmd = ETHTOOL_GCHANNELS;
req.ifr_data = (void*)&echannels;

    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCETHTOOL, &req) != 0)
        ERR("Can't get %s channels info! %s", nic, strerror(errno));
    else
        rx_no = echannels.rx_count;
```

Also i've try to get it from ethtool "ethtool -l eth0" with the same result:

```
#ethtool -l eth0
Channel parameters for eth0:
Cannot get device channel parameters
: Operation not supported
```

, but in /proc/interrupts i see that NIC have multiple RX rings binded to different CPU cores.
Anybody can tell me right way to get count of RX rings from C code?

Comment: Does your NIC supports RSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to get the ring counts of my NICs as well. After talking with someone more knowledgeable than I (who also wasn't figuring it out), we came to the agreement that you might have to check the specs for your NIC; that it doesn't seem to be something directly available through `ethtool`.

However, [this post](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) also shows that, by checking the indirection table, it can show the RX ring (but not TX ring) count:

```
$ sudo ethtool -x eth0
RX flow hash indirection table for eth3 with 2 RX ring(s):
0: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
8: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
16: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
24: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

However, on one of my machines I see:

```
$ sudo ethtool -x enp9s0
Cannot get RX ring count: Operation not supported
```

This is in spite of the [documentation for the NIC](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/datasheet/82574l-gbe-controller-datasheet.pdf) saying both:

- "The 82574L supports two transmit descriptor rings"
- "Figure 26 shows the structure of the two receive descriptor rings."

Hopefully either the `-x` option or checking the documentation for your NIC will help. It doesn't seem to be consistently and directly accessible via `ethtool`.